# Count distinct strings in rolling window using pandas + python (with a condition)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the number of distinct port numbers that exist between the current row and the 5 previous rows (sliding window) **and this when the same address appears.** 
For instance,

If the input is (csv file):

```
ID      PORT     ADDRESS
1        21       ad3 
2        22       ad1  
3        23       ad2
4        25       ad2 
5        25       ad1
6        22       ad1 
7        22       ad1
8        21       ad4
```

The output should be:

```
ID      PORT     ADDRESS      COUNT_DISC_PORT
1        21       ad3        -
2        22       ad1        -
3        23       ad2        - 
4        25       ad2        - 
5        25       ad1        - 
6        22       ad1        2 
7        23       ad1        3
8        21       ad4        1
```

I have read the documentation about the rolling function in pandas and I have tried combining group by and rolling with no success.

I am using Python 3.7 and the pandas package 0.22.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: 6        22       ad1        2 should it be 3 ?

Comment: @Wen no since I am just counting the distinct port number when ad1 appears (ports 22, 25, 22, so only 2 distinct).

Comment: If you are doing rolling window of size 6 (since you want previous 5), your first 5 rows should be empty because there's not enough rows before.

Comment: I find it out , two df, your print are different ....

Comment: @YilunZhang I have corrected the in\out, thanks.

Comment: Why `7        23       ad1        3`? Since it is `ad1`, it should count how many 23 in 5 rows above are there with `ADDRESS = ad1`, but that's the only one..

Answer (score 0):

`for index, row in df.iterrows():
    small_df = df[index - 5:index]
    df['uniques'][index] = len(small_df.unique())`

Here's my quick shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , seems like you data inout is mismatch with the df your show to us

```
df.groupby('ADDRESS').PORT.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x).rolling(5,min_periods=1).apply(lambda y: len(set(y))))
Out[844]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    2.0
Name: PORT, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks @Wen. I have corrected the input. Also, could you please provide me a little bit of explanations on your solutions? In particular, what the len() is doing...

Comment: @mig len(set()) count the unique value of each rolling windows

Comment: this does not always work because of the group by... Please see this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15DBSnFS_2l8N2OK_9JG_knRlmDAVAHSU/view?usp=sharing).