# Distinct Pairs in a Rolling Window Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to count the distinct pair values between ports to addresses.

Basically this exact scenario where i want the rolloing_count to be the number of times the PORT and ADDRESS value occur when the row enters the window.

[Count distinct strings in rolling window using pandas + python (with a condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057325/count-distinct-strings-in-rolling-window-using-pandas-python-with-a-condition)

However the answer to the question is incorrect and there was no follow-up resolving it.

Lets say I have the table

```
ID  PORT    ADDRESS  
1    21     ad3  
2    22     ad1       
3    23     ad2      
4    23     ad2            
5    21     ad4            
6    22     ad1            
7    22     ad1            
8    21     ad4
```

for example if I had the window size of 3 my desired output would be

```
 ID  PORT    ADDRESS  rolling_count
 1    21     ad3            1
 2    22     ad1            1
 3    23     ad2            1
 4    23     ad2            2
 5    21     ad4            1
 6    22     ad1            1
 7    22     ad1            2
 8    21     ad4            1
```

The linked post answer doesn't seem to only count within the window

```
df['rolling_count']=df.groupby('ADDRESS').PORT.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x).rolling(3,min_periods=1).apply(lambda y: len(set(y))))
```

is what I have tried to use and its not correct. This is what it is outputting

```
 ID  PORT    ADDRESS  rolling_count
 1    21     ad3            1
 2    22     ad1            1
 3    23     ad2            1
 4    23     ad2            1
 5    21     ad4            1
 6    22     ad1            1
 7    22     ad1            1
 8    21     ad4            1
```

Any feedback would be useful.

Comment: What is the desired output

Comment: I adjusted the question to make it more clear what the desired output would be

Comment: at index 4 the grouped object of 23 have only 2 values of same 'ad2', how it could be rolling count of 2 , can you specify @Haytes

Comment: when that count is made in the window would be index 2,3,4 to my understanding. Am I misunderstanding the approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

for your application, you may choose to count the repetitive values of port and address in a sequence
sample df

```
ID  PORT    ADDRESS
0   1   21  ad3
1   2   22  ad1
2   3   23  ad2
3   4   23  ad2
4   5   21  ad4
5   6   22  ad1
6   7   22  ad1
7   8   22  ad1

x = df.PORT.astype(str) + df.ADDRESS
x = (x.eq(x.shift())+ x.eq(x.shift(-1))).astype(int)
a = x == 1
b = a.cumsum()
arr = np.where(a, b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int), 1)
```

Out

```
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3])
```

rolling window actually keeps (windowlength -1) repetitive windows on a sequence w.r.t the window length you chosen for, which leads to count the values in different places.

```
from collections import Counter
def unique_values(x,window):
    # External numpy array to generate windows
    a = (np.arange(window)[None, :] + np.arange(len(x))[:, None])-(window-1)
    b = np.where(a<0,0,a)
    return [max(Counter(i).values()) for i in np.where(a<0,a,x.values.take(a))]
unique_values(df.PORT.astype(str) +df.ADDRESS,3)
```

Out:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]
```